# Python generating text file with way larger size than expected

Tags: python

I am trying to write the data recorded through a mic into a text file for encryption, 
here is my code,

```
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
        channels=CHANNELS,
        rate=RATE,
        input=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

with open("Original_Data.txt", 'wb') as outFile:
    for frame in frames:
        outFile.write(str(frame))
```

Clearly, the Audio data is stored in a list

```
frames[]
```

There will be total of `(44100/1024)*5 = 215` CHUNKS, so `215*1024 = 220160 bits`.

The file size should be,

```
220161 bits = 220161/8 = 27520 bytes
```

But the file that is created after the above code execute has a size of approx `880640 bytes`

Why this is happening ?

What I can anticipate is that, it is happening at the line when i am writing the data into a text file,

```
with open("Original_Data.txt", 'wb') as outFile:
    for frame in frames:
        outFile.write(str(frame))
```

But I am still not sure.
Does anybody has any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing stereo samples, not mono, so 1024 samples per channel is 2048 total samples.

And you're writing 16-bit samples, not 8-bit, and certainly not 1-bit.

So, 215 chunks of 4096 bytes each is 880640 bytes.

There's no way around it; that's how much space CD-quality sound takes up. At the cost of a little CPU power (and code), you can always add some compression—ideally something like FLAC, but even simple gzip will help. Or you can use lossy compression like MP3 or Speex to squeeze it down a lot smaller. Or you can use lower-quality sound—mono, 8-bit, 32k instead of 44k, etc.—in the first place (which is really just a form of lossy compression).

Comment: @SufiyanGhori: Yes, to use mono instead of stereo, use 1 channel. And if you want 8-bit samples, use int8 instead of int16 format.

Comment: for 2 channels, the size is 2048 samples. How come the size is twice of 2048 for bid depth of 16-bit ? i.e 4096 ? and what will be the size if i reduce the bit depth to 8-bit ?